# How to change cPanel URL? Example: mydomain.com/cpanel

Tags: security, cpanel, vps, httpd.conf, centos

I want to change my website's cPanel URL/path for security reasons. I have a VPS with shell root access, running centOS 6.5 64-bit. I want to change cPanel path for my website on the VPS to be something complicated like (mydomain.com/dj73db/dndpanel/) instead of (mydomain.com/cpanel). Does anyone knows how can this be done on a VPS environment? Appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the port numbers for cPanel, the WebHost Manager or Webmail. The port numbers are hard-coded into cPanel and there is no configuration option that allows them to be changed.

Even if you edit the httpd.conf file and change the ScriptAlias directives that cause /cpanel, /webmail and /whm to work, they will still be accessible via ports 2082/2083, 2095/2096, and 2086/2087, respectively